# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification from custom class issue

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a  customized UITableViewCell with textfields. The textfields of the cells are set to call for  delegate functions.
Inside

```
  -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
object:nil];

                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
object:nil];



                   if(textField == fromTF){

                        fromTF.text = [[[fromTF.text substringToIndex:2] stringByAppendingString:@":"] stringByAppendingString:[fromTF.text substringFromIndex:2]];
                        [toTF becomeFirstResponder];
                        return YES;
                    }
                    if(textField == toTF){
                        [toTF resignFirstResponder];
                        [intTF becomeFirstResponder];
                        return YES;

                      }

             return YES;
}
```

This is delegate method is called in my custom cell.However when called, the UIKeyBoardWillHideNotification addobserver object is not removed when pressed 'return' key. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you wrote addObserver notification for UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in custom cell class? Because you have given like removeObserver:self that means Observer also should be in same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Ganesh thank you for the answer. I removed the resignFirstResponder and passed the firstResponder directly to the next textfield. This prevented the keyboard from disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

and also check this link [textFieldShouldBeginEditing + UIKeyboardWillShowNotification + OS 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979531/textfieldshouldbeginediting-uikeyboardwillshownotification-os-3-2?rq=1)

it may help you.